# CoreSpotlight indexing not working

Tags: ios, swift, search, ios9, corespotlight

I am using the CoreSpotLight api to index some content. For some reason I am not able to find the data when I search in the
SpotLight.

```
let atset:CSSearchableItemAttributeSet = CSSearchableItemAttributeSet()  
atset.title = "Simple title"  
atset.contentDescription = "Simple twitter search"  
let item = CSSearchableItem(uniqueIdentifier: "id1", domainIdentifier: "com.shrikar.twitter.search", attributeSet: atset)  
CSSearchableIndex.defaultSearchableIndex().indexSearchableItems([item]) { (error) -> Void in  
 print("Indexed")  
}
```

When I run the app I see that the data is indexed and the error is nil.
Also I have added the CoreSpotLight and MobileCoreServices to the build phase.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try use `itemContentType` initializer like so :

```
let atset:CSSearchableItemAttributeSet = CSSearchableItemAttributeSet(itemContentType: kUTTypeImage as String)
atset.title = "Simple title"
atset.contentDescription = "Simple twitter search"
let item = CSSearchableItem(uniqueIdentifier: "id1", domainIdentifier: "com.shrikar.twitter.search", attributeSet: atset)
CSSearchableIndex.defaultSearchableIndex().indexSearchableItems([item]) { (error) -> Void in
    print("Indexed")  
}
```

The `kUTTypeImage` is declared in `MobileCoreServices`.

Comment: I tried the same code as mentioned in the docs but its not working.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem... Sorry I can not help you

Comment: @Shrikar I tried Bannings code and it is working. I think you are expecting result to come on top, try to scroll down in search to see your result if it appears there.

Comment: @Ayush looks like that was the issue.

Comment: @Shrikar can you please reply with answer on Apple developer forum.